# Is there a general method to solve diophantine equations of the form $x^2+Ay=C$

Tags: quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity, pell-type-equations

For example

$$x^2+7y=9$$I'm thinking something maybe along the lines of Pell's equation but not sure. Any help appreciated, been several years since I've last dealt with Pell equations and quadratic recipriocity.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$-7y=x^2-9=(x+3)(x-3)$$
Hence we need either $x+3$ to be a multiple of $7$, or $x-3$ to be a multiple of $7$.  Thus $x\equiv \pm 3\pmod{7}$.  Any such $x$ will work, with $y$ specified uniquely given $x$.

---

More generally, if $C$ is a square modulo $A$, i.e. $C\equiv D^2\pmod{A}$ for some $D\in\mathbb{Z}$, then for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $C=D^2+kA$ and hence $$x^2+Ay=D^2+kA$$ which we rewrite as $$A(k-y)=(x-D)(x+D)$$
Now we need $A$ to divide $(x-D)(x+D)$.  If $A$ is prime, it must divide one or the other, but if $A$ is composite it might partly divide each.  Once $x$ is chosen so that $A|(x-D)(x+D)$, $y$ is determined uniquely.  In particular, solutions will always exist, by taking $x\equiv \pm D\pmod{A}$ (but other $x$'s might work too).

---

If $C$ is not a square modulo $A$ I dunno.

Comment: yes, that's easy, but the post requires a "general" method (= C is not square)